# How to use ADF CreateInsert when having a sequence generated ID trigger in my database?

Tags: java, jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I'm having an exception all the time when trying to add a new entity :

All fields are filled in, only ID is missing.

I'm adding an image :

[image: Visual Problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For solving this problem it is necessary to change **the type of the entity**. Open the Entity Object, go to attributes tab, select ID field and in property inspector tab change **Type NUMBER** to DBSequence.

[image: Visual Solution]

**In the case that you have an ID of type BigDecimal**, it's necessary to double click the attribute to make appear "Edit Attribute" Popup, then in browse for the Type label, and search oracle.jpo.doman.DBSequence, then do OK.

[image: Edit Attribute Popup after clicking Browse button]

[image: Browning Hierarchy tab until finding DBSequence]